# tcolorbox: how to set a coordinate in the box which can be used by the finish key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to connect the frame of a tcolorbox with some of the content but have difficulties to set a suitable tikz node: The finish environment seems not to use the remember picture key and so tikzmark doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
                  finish={
                          \draw[green,thick](pic cs:B)--(frame.south);
                         }
                 ]
Bla B\tikzmark{B}
\par
\bigskip

Bla\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[blue,->](0,0)--(pic cs:B);
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get the green line to point to the B like the blue line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need `remember` option which is defined as `tikz={remember picture}` in `tcbskins.code.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, remember, 
                  finish={
                          \draw[green,thick](pic cs:B)--(frame.south);
                         }
                 ]
Bla B\tikzmark{B}
\par
\bigskip

Bla\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[blue,->](0,0)--(pic cs:B);
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew there must be something but I couldn't find it and now I see it is only two pages away from the description of the finish key ... thanks.